# Spring MVC validation is it possible to validate non-primitive fields

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to perform  cross field validation on a HashSet using custom validator. however in my annotation i get the following error

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Custom {
    String message() default "{Custom}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    Set<Custom> land();
}
```

Invalid type Set for the annotation attribute ; only primitive type, String, Class, annotation, enumeration are permitted or 1-dimensional arrays thereof

the fucntionality i am trying to achieve is that my application expects this set to be populated before the next page can be loaded.

is it possible to carry this validation out using a non primitive type or do i need to look at another way to validate this entry

Answer (score -1):

Just read [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html). Create validator and use it